# SharePoint Online personalized themes

Tags: sharepoint-online, branding, personalization

https://channel9.msdn.com/blogs/OfficeDevPnP/PnP-Add-In-Transformation-Training-module-3-Branding-with-add-in-model

In the video at duration 00:30:36 there is a mention of personal themes for end users. Please let me know how to implement it. I have requirement of letting end users choose and apply one brand out of available brand options to the sharepoint online site.(If user1 chooses brand1, other users should continue with their respective brand look and feel.)

Answer (score 1):

The theme mentioned in the video can be selected by individual users as follows:

1) Go to https://portal.office.com/account/#settings in the tenant

2) By default, if no theme is applied you will see it as below:

[image]

3) If you click on theme, you will see a list of options as below:

[image]

4) Select the theme you want. I selected `Beach sunset` theme and clicked on Save.

5) After that, all Apps like Yammer, OneDrive, Outlook , SharePoint sites etc will have this theme.

Previously, i had the default theme which shows a blue-ish background.
[image]

After applying the theme and waiting for a few minutes, it gets changed as below:

[image]

By doing this, only my individual theme would be changed and for other users it would remain as before.

Reference - [Personalize Office 365 themes](https://blogs.office.com/2014/09/02/personalize-office-365-experience-selecting-themes/)

To allow these themes to work for individual users , you need to have "Prevent users from overriding custom theming with their own theme" setting unchecked at the tenant level.

Follow below steps:

1) Go to https://portal.office.com/adminportal/home#/companyprofile (login as tenant admin)

2) In the "Manage custom themes for your organization", section click Edit

[image]

3) Uncheck the "Prevent users from overriding custom theming with their own theme" option and click Save.

[image]